# Java Selenium - How to click on a button link element with no ID?

Tags: java, selenium, maven, webdriver

I've been trying to get the WebDriver to find the element by xpath and using the href link directly behind the button, however to no avail.
Here's my code so far:

```
package mavensample;

import.java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class mavensample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriverpath";
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, Timeunit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, Timeunit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://initialLink.net/");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='https://censoredlink.net/']"));
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(“a[href=‘https://webqa.cenpos.net/vt/‘]”)));
}}
```

This is the elemnt info I get on inspect: **a href= "https://censoredlink.net/" class="btn btn-sm btn-light mb-1" target="_blank">QA**

I would normally locate the element through text, however there are multiple different QA buttons for different environments. I tried using CssSelector and just inputting the link directly however that didn't work either.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In case `https://censoredlink.net/` is unique value for `href` attribute you can try the following XPath:

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='https://censoredlink.net/']"))
```

Or with CssSelector

```java
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='https://censoredlink.net/']"))
```

**UPD**
I guess you are missing a wait. I mean you need to wait for the element to be loaded before accessing it. The best way to do that is to use `WebDriverWait`.
Also it's possible the element is inside iframe etc.
We need to see that page...

Comment: Please update your question with all your code, make it readable. If possible including the URL

Comment: I updated the question, let me know if you do need the actual link and I'll update it with that.

Comment: Definitely yes, if it possible

Comment: @Prophet : It was a typo error, you didn't realize. check your xpath and css selector. `)`  this present inside string.

Comment: @KunduK I see, thanks. But also possibly he needs to add a delay / wait, also there maybe an iframe there etc.

Comment: The censored link is: https://svdlknxtgapp01a.servers.global.prv/sqatools/ - I think it might not be accessible to anyone not on the VPN/proxy

Comment: Are you sure there is no typo in the link? It can't be opened

Comment: Anyway, have you tried the fixed locator expression? Adding a delay before that command?

Comment: I just tried adding WebDriverWait, and I'm getting the error "cannot be resolved to a type" for that, as well as ExpectedConditions cannot be resolved. I imported both expectedconditions as well as WebDriverWait

Comment: I can't see where and how you tried to use `WebDriverWait` or `ExpectedConditions`. Looks like you even not fixed the locator string as Kunduk mentioned.

Comment: Hey @Prophet, please check the updated code and sorry for the delayed response. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo error in your `css selector`. you need to remove `)` this

Instead of this

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='https://censoredlink.net/')]"));
```

It should have been

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='https://censoredlink.net/']"));
```